# Unable to resize dashboard slices in superset

Tags: apache-superset

I'm using apache-superset python package to build a dashboard. I'm unable to re-arrange/resize the plots in the dashboard. As per the [documentation](https://superset.apache.org/tutorial.html),

> you can adjust the size of slices in a dashboard by clicking, holding and dragging the bottom-right corner to your desired dimensions

but this doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a recent-enough version of superset, you should see a small caret at the bottom right of each slice. Like this:
[image: slice caret]

You should be able to click, hold, and drag it to adjust your slice height and width.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the apache-superset python package version 0.35.1, but I'm not able to see the caret as per your screenshot.

Comment: The caret icon appears only when the dashboard is in edit mode in case anyone else struggles with this.

Answer (score 0):

Crete Angular app in which create created superset module.
Add this code in **superset.component.html**

superset.component.html

```html
<div id='superset-container'></div>
```

Add this code to your **superset.component.ts** file in **ngOnInit()**
method
this code reference I have taken from [Superset Embedded SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superset-ui/embedded-sdk?activeTab=readme).
For token you have to write your logic for getting token from apache superset inside this method **fetchGuestTokenFromBackend()**.

```js
    const mountPoint = document.getElementById("superset-container");

    const token = await this.fetchGuestTokenFromBackend();
    await await this.fetchGuestTokenFromBackend().then(e=>{
        this.guest_token=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)).token;
      });
    embedDashboard({
        id: "25579002-9e70-401e-aca2-ef8ceb220fd0",  // given by the Superset embedding UI
        supersetDomain: "https://localhost:8088",
        mountPoint: mountPoint,
        fetchGuestToken: async () => this.guest_token,
        dashboardUiConfig: { hideTitle: true },
     });
```

Add this code to your **superset.component.css** file to resize the
superset dashboard.
superset.component.css

```css
    div#superset-container>>>iframe  {
      border: 0;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 500px;
    }
```

## **The complete code is here.**

superset.component.ts

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { embedDashboard, EmbedDashboardParams, Size } from "@superset-ui/embedded-sdk";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-superset',
  templateUrl: './superset.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./superset.component.css']
})
export class SupersetComponent implements OnInit {


  access_token:string;
  guest_token:string;
  constructor(public http:HttpClient) {}
  async ngOnInit(){
    const mountPoint = document.getElementById("superset-container");
    const token = await this.fetchGuestTokenFromBackend();
    await await this.fetchGuestTokenFromBackend().then(e=>{
        this.guest_token=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)).token;
      });
    embedDashboard({
        id: "25579002-9e70-401e-aca2-ef8ceb220fd0",  // given by the Superset embedding UI
        supersetDomain: "https://localhost:8088",
        mountPoint: mountPoint,
        fetchGuestToken: async () => this.guest_token,
        dashboardUiConfig: { hideTitle: true },
     });
  }


    async fetchGuestTokenFromBackend(): Promise<string> {
      await this.fetchMainTokenFromBackend().then(e=>{
      this.access_token=e.access_token;
      });
      const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Authorization':'Bearer '+this.access_token
      })
    };
    const body={
    "user": {
        "username": "admin",
        "first_name": "admin",
        "last_name": "admin"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "dashboard",
            "id": "25579002-9e70-401e-aca2-ef8ceb220fd0"
        }
    ],
    "rls": [
        {
            "clause": "customer_id=1"
        }
    ]
    }
    return this.http.post<string>("https://localhost:8088/api/v1/security/guest_token/",body,httpOptions).toPromise();
 }

 fetchMainTokenFromBackend(): Promise<any> {
   const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      })
    };
    const body={
      "password":"admin",
      "provider":"db",
      "refresh":true,
      "username":"admin"
      }
  return this.http.post("https://localhost:8088/api/v1/security/login",body,httpOptions).toPromise();
 }
   
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?